# Cannot open database. Login failed for user error when creating SQL Server database while installing a .NET app

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, connection-string

I have created a .net app with VS 2010 and SQL Server 2008 database. I deployed the app following the instructions in this link:
http://techbrij.com/install-sql-server-database-with-visual-studio-setup

But every time I install the app, I get an exception:

> Cannot open database "PharmacyDb" requested by the login.the login failed. Login failed for user 'Bahaa-PC\Bahaa".

I try run the installing as administrator and allow SQL Server through Windows firewall but I still get this exception.

Note: I have 3 SQL script files to create my database, and when I execute them in VS or SQL Server Management Studio, they create the database perfectly.

What have I missed?

Note2: this is the connection string in install.cs class:

```
 string connStr = "Data Source=" + serverName + ";Initial Catalog=" + dbName + ";Integrated Security=True";
```

Updated:
log file:

```html
2017-05-13 13:13:17.60 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 38.
2017-05-13 13:13:17.60 Logon       Login failed for user 'Bahaa-PC\Bahaa'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database. [CLIENT: <local machine>]
2017-05-13 13:23:10.03 spid52      Attempting to load library 'xpstar.dll' into memory. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2017-05-13 13:23:10.10 spid52      Using 'xpstar.dll' version '2009.100.1600' to execute extended stored procedure 'xp_instance_regread'. This is an informational message only; no user action is required.
2017-05-13 13:24:34.49 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 38.
2017-05-13 13:24:34.49 Logon       Login failed for user 'Bahaa-PC\Bahaa'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database. [CLIENT: <local machine>]
2017-05-13 13:35:12.71 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 38.
2017-05-13 13:35:12.71 Logon       Login failed for user 'Bahaa-PC\Bahaa'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database. [CLIENT: <local machine>]
2017-05-13 13:36:55.95 spid53      Attempting to load library 'xplog70.dll' into memory. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2017-05-13 13:36:55.99 spid53      Using 'xplog70.dll' version '2009.100.1600' to execute extended stored procedure 'xp_msver'. This is an informational message only; no user action is required.
2017-05-13 14:03:27.26 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 38.
2017-05-13 14:03:27.26 Logon       Login failed for user 'Bahaa-PC\Bahaa'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database. [CLIENT: <local machine>]
2017-05-13 14:07:27.27 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 38.
2017-05-13 14:07:27.27 Logon       Login failed for user 'Bahaa-PC\Bahaa'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database. [CLIENT: <local machine>]
2017-05-13 14:07:56.66 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 38.
2017-05-13 14:07:56.66 Logon       Login failed for user 'Bahaa-PC\Bahaa'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database. [CLIENT: <local machine>]
2017-05-13 14:11:45.57 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 38.
2017-05-13 14:11:45.57 Logon       Login failed for user 'Bahaa-PC\Bahaa'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database. [CLIENT: <local machine>]
2017-05-14 00:37:36.40 Server      Server resumed execution after being idle 35916 seconds: user activity awakened the server. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2017-05-14 00:37:41.48 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 38.
2017-05-14 00:37:41.48 Logon       Login failed for user 'Bahaa-PC\Bahaa'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database. [CLIENT: <local machine>]
```

Comment: Check the SQL Server error log. It should have a message with the specific reason the login failed.

Comment: Is the sql sever in the same box? its trying to use windows authentication so make sure Bahaa-PC\Bahaa has access to your SQL server. If the DB is different box try to use SQL authentication  and change connection string.

Comment: @Dan: The log hasn't any unusual info

Comment: @NMK: user Bahaa-PC\Bahaa  is able to connect to to sql server instance not to the database

Comment: @BahaaSalaheldin, there should be a message in the SQL error log for the login failed, which should have additional information about the cause. If the user doesn't have access to the database, it will have reason "Failed to open the explicitly specified database...".

Comment: @Dan: yes I found some error messages in log file, I updataed the question to display log messages.

Comment: @BahaaSalaheldin, the error means that either the user doesn't have permissions to access the database or it is unavailable (doesn't exist or offline).

Comment: I think the data base isn't exist as after the failure I check Sql server  and I don't found the data base, but I'm sure the sql script is validated well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many attempts I found the problem was that I use an object which need a connection to the data base in the installer class, so I removed it.